# Check if string contains substring matching regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm writing a script to check if there's occurence of amex credit card number inside a string.

My code looks like this:

```
let amexRegex= /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/;

if(text.search(amexRegex) != -1){
    console.log('Found!');
} else {
    console.log('Not found!');
}
```

When I set `text`to `'378734493671000'` (a valid amex credit card number), script prints out `Found!`, but if I keep that same text and add some text arround it, like this: `'378734493671000 ABCDEFG'`, it prints out `Not found!`.

What should I change in order to find occurence of substring matching the regex?
I don't need a index of substring matching the regex, just true\false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention that only removing `^` and `$` can lead to incorrect matches, such as longer numeric strings.
You better replace them by word boundaries:

```
\b3[47][0-9]{13}\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nz8wMi/1)

Answer (score 2):

The `^` and `$` restrict matching to beginning and end of string, respectively. It's probably enough to remove those.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove `^` and `$` which respectively match stat and end of line:

```
let amexRegex= /3[47][0-9]{13}/;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let amexRegex = /3[47][0-9]{13}/

if(amenxRegex.test(text) {
  console.log('Found!')
} else {
  console.log('Not found!')
}
```